# OAuth AJAX Calls to MVC Controller - Issues with OPTIONS and CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, oauth, asp.net-core-mvc

Order Management

TestRefManual.OrderableTestManual.DefaultTargetStateId
TestRefManual.PromptDefaultValue

NettingRouting

TestRefManual.OrderableTestRoutingManual (CanThawAndMix, CanOcr, IsCombinedDtaRouting)

I have a MVC application that sometimes makes AJAX calls to the MVC controller.  Once the user has been logged in, this works fine (the cookie is used to allow the call to go through).

But if the cookie / token has expired (or some other reason that an AJAX call is made with out a valid cookie/token), then it fails with a CORS error.

I am analyzed the call traffic for a call protected by `[authorize]`.  I made a call using a server side operation, an AJAX call and a call from a SPA application.  Both the server side operation and the SPA application work just fine.  Only the AJAX call fails.

Here is what happens:  (The bolded line is the important one. These happen for all 3 unless otherwise specified)

- The call is made to the `[authorize]` protected MVC operation. (`myIDP.net/home/AjaxCall`)
- The call is redirected via a 302 to the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint.
- [AJAX ONLY] - An OPTIONS call is made to the `myIDP.net/oauth2/authorize` endpoint.  It returns a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:44382` in the header.
- The GET to `myIDP.net/oauth2/authorize` is sent.  It returns a 302 to redirect to `myIDP.net/authentication/login.do`
- **[AJAX  ONLY] - An OPTIONS call is made to `myIDP.net/authentication/login.do`  It does NOT return a header with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  In fact, it seems to return the exact same content as if the call had been a GET.  This causes a CORS error in the browser.**
- [ALL BUT AJAX] - A GET call is made to `myIDP.net/authentication/login.do`  Its response is the exact same as the OPTIONS call made by the AJAX flow.
- [ALL BUT AJAX] - Flow continues on to login successfully.

It is interesting to me that the SPA app does not do an OPTIONS but the AJAX one does.  They are both Javascript based, I would expect the browser to work the same for both of them.  But not doing the OPTIONS call seems to be what is working.

**How can I convince AJAX to not do the OPTIONS calls?**

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the URL used for the AJAX call not having the same case actual application.  Once they had the same case, it was resolved.